# JavaFX ScrollBar Scene Builder

Tags: javafx

So basically I am trying to add ScrollBar to my JavaFX application from Scene Builder, but since i just started learning JavaFX, i don't really know how to do it. For example, I'm using StackPane, and i have some kind of form that i cant wrap in predefined window size so i need ScrollBar so the user can scroll through form. I referenced to this code provided by Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/ScrollBarSample.java.html
But it doesn't help. I don't know if that is because of StackPane, because when i run this code snippet in HBox(as they gave it) it works just fine.
So this is what i did:

```
scrollBar.setLayoutX(700.0d);
scrollBar.setMin(0);
scrollBar.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
scrollBar.setPrefHeight(600);
scrollBar.setMax(1000);

    scrollBar.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov,
            Number old_val, Number new_val) {
                pane.setLayoutY(-new_val.doubleValue());
        }
    });
```

scrollBar - fx:id for the ScrollBar component in Scene Builder
pane - fx:id for the StackPanel component in Scene Builder

So basically with all of this code it behaves as default, nothing changes. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use a scrollPane? I've created you a little form, which is too small for its window. As you will hopefully see, the form will scroll inside its scrollPane.

Class1:

```
  import javafx.application.Application;
  import javafx.scene.Scene;
  import javafx.stage.Stage;

  public class RunTest extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
     primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
     Test test = new Test();
     Scene scene = new Scene(test, 100, 100);
     primaryStage.setScene(scene);
     primaryStage.show();
  }
 }
```

Class2:

```
 import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
 import javafx.event.EventHandler;
 import javafx.scene.control.*;
 import javafx.scene.layout.*;

 public class Test extends StackPane {

     ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
     VBox vBox = new VBox();
     TextField aTextField = new TextField();
     Label aLabel = new Label("a Field");
     TextField aTextField2 = new TextField();
     Label aLabel2 = new Label("a Field2");
     TextField aTextField3 = new TextField();
     Label aLabel3 = new Label("a Field3");
     Button button = new Button("Press");

     public Test() {
         setMaxSize(100, 50);
         vBox.setMaxSize(95, 45);
         vBox.getChildren().setAll(aLabel, aTextField, aLabel2, aTextField2, aLabel3, aTextField3, button);
         scrollPane.setContent(vBox);
         scrollPane.setPrefSize(95,45);
         getChildren().addAll(scrollPane);
     }
 }
```

To see without a scrollpane, change these 3 lines to look like this:

```
 //        scrollPane.setContent(vBox);
 //        scrollPane.setPrefSize(95,45);
           getChildren().addAll(vBox);
```